# traefik setup on gke not working

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, google-kubernetes-engine

I’m trying to get `traefik` running in GKE, following the  user guide (https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/).

Instead of seeing the dashboard, I get a `404`. I guess there’s a problem with the RBAC setup somewhere but I can’t figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The ingress controller log shows a constant flow of (one each second):

> E0714 12:19:56.665790       1 reflector.go:205]
>   github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86:
>   Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User
>   "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot
>   list services at the cluster scope: Unknown user
>   "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller"

and the traefik pod itself constantly spews:

> E0714 12:17:45.108356       1 reflector.go:205]
>   github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86:
>   Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: ingresses.extensions is forbidden:
>   User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list
>   ingresses.extensions in the namespace "kube-system": Unknown user
>   "system:serviceaccount:default:default"
>
> E0714 12:17:45.708160       1 reflector.go:205]
>   github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86:
>   Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User
>   "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list services in the
>   namespace "default": Unknown user
>   "system:serviceaccount:default:default"
>
> E0714 12:17:45.714057       1 reflector.go:205]
>   github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86:
>   Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: endpoints is forbidden: User
>   "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list endpoints in the
>   namespace "kube-system": Unknown user
>   "system:serviceaccount:default:default"
>
> E0714 12:17:45.714829       1 reflector.go:205]
>   github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86:
>   Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: ingresses.extensions is forbidden:
>   User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list
>   ingresses.extensions in the namespace "default": Unknown user
>   "system:serviceaccount:default:default"
>
> E0714 12:17:45.715653       1 reflector.go:205]
>   github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86:
>   Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: endpoints is forbidden: User
>   "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list endpoints in the
>   namespace "default": Unknown user
>   "system:serviceaccount:default:default"
>
> E0714 12:17:45.716659       1 reflector.go:205]
>   github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:86:
>   Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User
>   "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list services in the
>   namespace "kube-system": Unknown user
>   "system:serviceaccount:default:default"

I created the clusterrole using:

```
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["servies", "endpoints", "secrets"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["extensions"]
    resources: ["ingresses"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
```

and then deployed traefik as deployment:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
        name: traefik-ingress-lb
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - image: traefik
        name: traefik-ingress-lb
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: admin
          containerPort: 8080
        args:
        - --api
        - --kubernetes
        - --logLevel=INFO
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      name: web
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      name: admin
  type: LoadBalancer
```

when using helm to install traefik I used the following values file:

```
dashboard:
  enabled: true
  domain: traefik.example.com
kubernetes:
  namespaces:
    - default
    - kube-system
```

and finally, for the UI I used the following yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  rules:
  - host: traefik.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: traefik-web-ui
          servicePort: web
```

thanks for looking!

(edit: corrected typo in title)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the namespace "kube-system" is handled by the Master node, you will not be able to deploy anything on that specific namespace. The Master node within GKE is a managed service and is not accessible to users at this time.

If you would like to have this functionality, then the only suggestion I can provide at this time is to create your own [custom cluster from scratch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/scratch/). This will allow you to have access to the Master Node and you would have the option to customize your cluster to your liking.

Edit: I was able to find instructions from [github](https://github.com/Zenika/traefik-gke-demo) on how to use Traefik as a GKE loadbalancer. I would suggest testing this first before running it in your production cluster.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! does that mean that traefik won't work in gke at all? i have absolutely no interest in building my own cluster, did it once for educational purposes but that's nothing i want to run as production infrastructure.

Comment: thanks for finding that little gem - i'll have a go at it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you're setting up a ClusterRoleBinding with name "traefik-ingress-controller" and namespace "kube-system" but Traefik is running in namespace default with serviceaccount default.

Try changing your ClusterRoleBinding to:

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
 namespace: default
```

Or deploy your system with serviceaccount "traefik-ingress-controller" and in namespace "kube-system"